# меню в include (php)

Tags: php, css

Делаю меню в include. 
Есть массив с пунктами меню и с персональными ссылками.

```html
$menuItems = array(
  array ("link"=>"Главная", "href"=>"index.php"),
  array ("link"=>"Блог", "href"=>"index.php#blog"),
  array ("link"=>"Правила проекта", "href"=>"rules.php"),
  array ("link"=>"Личный кабинет", "href"=>"#"), 
);
```

И есть конструктор меню, в котором хочу добавить проверку через if. Проверка нужна для того, чтобы на главной странице поменять ссылку во втором пункте меню на якорь "#blog".

Пример конструктора:

```
echo '<ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">';
    foreach($menuItems as $menuItemId) {
       echo "<li><a href='{$menuItemId[href]}'> {$menuItemId[link]}</a></li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

**Вопрос:** как сделать эту проверку?

Comment: `foreach($menuItems as $menuItemId) {if(true) echo "<li><a href='{$menuItemId[href]}'> {$menuItemId[link]}</a></li>";};`

Comment: Вариант номер 2: `foreach($menuItems as $menuItemId) if(true) { echo "<li><a href='{$menuItemId[href]}'> {$menuItemId[link]}</a></li>";};`

Comment: `$i=0;
foreach($menuItems as $menuItemId) { $i++;if($i==1/*второй пункт меню*/)echo "<li><a href='{$menuItemId[href]}'> {$menuItemId[link]}</a></li>";};`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ваши примеры подойдут, если проверка будет проводиться только на одной страничке. У меня проверка будет проводиться на каждой странице. Через include же делаю :(

Comment: Еще вариант: `foreach($menuItems as $menuItemId) if($menuItemId[link]=='Блог'){ echo "<li><a href='{$menuItemId[href]}'> {$menuItemId[link]}</a></li>";};`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а вот последний вариант можно разкрутить. Попробую сейчас

Comment: Тогда уточните что именно вам непонятно?) как проверить текущую ссылку или что именно? в отрыве от остального кода - нипанятна что вы хотите

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков мне нужно что-то на подобии такого: if ($menuItemId[link]=='Главная') { поменять значение в многомерном масиве }

Comment: Что вы хотите проверить? словами, русскими, не кодом. Проверить текущую страницу(на которую зашел пользователь)?Проверить массив и модифицировать ссылку у определенного элемента?

Comment: не забывайте `[href]` и `[link]` свои в кавычки оборачивать **везде**.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков именно так)

Comment: @teran или использовать дефайны(!шутка)

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - хранит текущую страницу

```
define('link','link');
define('href','href');
$menuItems = array(
  array ("link"=>"Главная", "href"=>"index.php"),
  array ("link"=>"Блог", "href"=>"index.php#blog"),
  array ("link"=>"Правила проекта", "href"=>"rules.php"),
  array ("link"=>"Личный кабинет", "href"=>"#"), 
);
foreach($menuItems $key => $val)
{
  if(
      ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/index.php')  //проверяем текущую страницу
    &&                                             // and = && = "логическое и"
      ($val[link]=='Блог')                     //проверяем очередную ссылку
    )
      echo "<li><a href='{$val[href]}'> {$val[link]}</a></li>";
  else
      echo "<li><a href='{$val[href]}'> {$val[link]}</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой вопрос очень примитивный))) 
Извините за мой "кретинизм")

Нужно было после масива добавить вот это:

```html
if ($menuItemId[link] = "Главная"){ $menuItems[2][href] = "#blog"; }
```